# In Org Mode, how do I link to internal documentation?

Tags: org-mode, documentation, hyperlinks

I want to create a clickable-link in my Org file directly to documentation built into Emacs. Is this possible to do? The documentation I want to link to are:

- Emacs Lisp Intro
- The GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When in a certain buffer one can use `M-x org-store-link` to find the correct syntax for linking to that file.

For linking to internal documentation you can use the following links:

```
info:elisp#Introduction
info:elisp
```

The first will take you to the Elisp Intro, the second to the Reference Manual.
Whenever you may wish to link to an info document, use the following syntax:

```
info:file#node
```

The `file` and `node` names are always listed *on the top of any info file*. In case the node name has spaces, then you'll have to use bracketed links, i.e.:

```
For entry "File: emacs.info,  Node: User Input" use

[[info:emacs#User Input]]
```

To explore the documentation, use the command `info-manual`, which is bound to `C-h r`.

Comment: Hi @dangom, that works well thank you. I did not say explicitly in my question but I would also like to know how to find out what that link is to a particular document or particular node of that document. Could you help out with that? I might ask this as another question altogether.

Comment: Of course. See updated answer.

Comment: node names are case sensitive for `info` command but not in [tag:emacs] (`info.el`)

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to use a `#` as separator for the last part instead, e.g. `[[info:elisp#Frame Layout]]`. This was in Emacs 27, if that makes a difference. What also helped me to figure this out was to use `org-store-link` in the appropriate place.

Comment: Just a side note: `ol-info` has to be loaded for this to work. It is loaded by default, but some custom configurations may disable this feature.